# Checking for OS in WIX Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an Installer for my application. The application is supported on Windows XP, Windows Vista & Windows 7. If User tries to install on some other OS, it should show a message to the user that the OS is not supported. I know I can add a check using VersionNT Property in Windows Installer.
But according to the values given here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370556(v=vs.85).aspx

If I check VersionNt=600, Then it allows the product to be Installed on Windows Vista as well as Server 2008 because both have VersionNT = 600. How can I allow user to only support Vista in this case and not Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [MsiNTProductType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370329.aspx) and require it equals 1 (Workstation).

Comment: I think it's rare that this is a valid requirement in the first place.  I'd reconsider the business rule.